# Chrome or FF web dev tools, how to reload page with network monitor off?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, firefox-developer-tools

I'm trying to monitor the network requests to a site one by one as they happen.
In Firefox or Chrome developer tools, there is the red "record" button for enabling/disabling network monitor recording, **however if I the button is off and I reload the page, it automatically turns itself on again and before I can click on it again, 30+ requests have been logged...**

what am I missing here? is there a firefox about:config option I could change to set the Network Monitor Record button to "off" by default?

Comment: Why don't you just clear the logs (trash icon in FF, crossed circle in Chrome)

Comment: I do that, but then I still cannot reload the page with Record "off"...annoying because I need to catch the first few requests

Comment: But you need it *on*  "to catch the first few requests."

Answer (score 0):

**Chrome only:** instead of refreshing the page/devtools normally (via <kbd>F5</kbd> key or the toolbar icon), paste and run `location.reload()` in devtools console.